# How to get payment reference number from paypal curl response in php

Tags: curl, paypal, reference, numbers, response

I want  payment reference number from paypal curl response in php
but not getting reference number in response
following is request i made :-

can anyone have idea about , how i can get reference number from curl response , or i am getting wrong somewhere in curl request ?

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
CURLOPT_URL => 'https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment',
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $paymentJson,
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
'Authorization: Bearer ' . $accessToken,
'Content-Type: application/json',
'Cookie: cookie_check=yes; ui_experience=d_id%3D83f0753501654cbf94ee30789ad96f6c1610704307225; ts=vreXpYrS%3D1705312306%26vteXpYrS%3D1610706106%26vr%3Df6bc3f351760a4be4056d862fffa1217%26vt%3D057541121770a78050dba8bfffa9d7eb%26vtyp%3Dreturn; ts_c=vr%3Df6bc3f351760a4be4056d862fffa1217%26vt%3D057541121770a78050dba8bfffa9d7eb'
)
));
$response = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
$result   = json_decode($response, TRUE);
```

getting `$result` as :-

```
Array
(
[id] => PAYID-MFBR34I2D9383578Y5951435
[intent] => sale
[state] => created
[payer] => Array
(
[payment_method] => paypal
)
[transactions] => Array
(
[0] => Array
(
[amount] => Array
(
[total] => 1785.00
[currency] => EUR
[details] => Array
(
[subtotal] => 1350.00
[tax] => 285.00
[shipping] => 0.00
[insurance] => 0.00
[handling_fee] => 150.00
[shipping_discount] => 0.00
)
)
[description] => This is the payment transaction description.
[custom] => This is the payment transaction description.
[invoice_number] => 159916
[soft_descriptor] => This is the payment transaction description.
[item_list] => Array
(
[items] => Array
(
[0] => Array
(
[name] => Item 1
[sku] => 1
[description] => This is the payment transaction description.
[price] => 1350.00
[currency] => EUR
[quantity] => 1
)
)
)
[related_resources] => Array
(
)
)
)
[note_to_payer] => Vimtox
[create_time] => 2021-09-16T10:35:29Z
[links] => Array
(
[0] => Array
(
[href] => https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAYID-MFBR34I2D9383578Y5951435
[rel] => self
[method] => GET
)
[1] => Array
(
[href] => https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=EC-4R254380AW710703U
[rel] => approval_url
[method] => REDIRECT
)
[2] => Array
(
[href] => https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAYID-MFBR34I2D9383578Y5951435/execute
[rel] => execute
[method] => POST
)
)
)
```

can anyone having solution for this ?

Answer (score 1):

What is a "reference number" ? Where would such a number come from? Please be specific in your question.

If you are looking for the PayPal transaction ID, that would be the v1/payments API's sale ID, which you will only receive after executing the payment. This must be done after the buyer approves it.

---

However, more importantly, the v1/payments API is deprecated, and should not be used for any new integrations. Use the current v2/checkout/orders API instead....:

Make two routes on your server, one for 'Create Order' and one for 'Capture Order', [documented here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/server-side-api-calls/#server-side-api-calls). These routes should return only JSON data (no HTML or text). When a capture response is successful, store its resulting payment details in your database (particularly `purchase_units[0].payments.captures[0].id`, the PayPal transaction ID) and perform any necessary business logic (such as sending confirmation emails or reserving product) before sending your return JSON.

Pair those two routes with the following approval flow: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server